# Two labels in one div, but not the same line

Tags: html, css

my code is like:

```
    <div data-role="content" class="ui-content" id="jobModuleContent">
        <div id="jmc_cJobNr"></div>
    </div>
```

In the div with id `jmc_cJobNr` there should be two `<label>`s, one on the left and the other on the right side. i thought the solution could be handling the elements with `style="text-align:left/right"`. it works, but not the way it is supposed to, because one label takes a whole line in the div, the other label is a line below.

Any suggestions how to fix that?

Comment: can u post it on jsfiddle

Comment: float one label to the left and other to the right. ex: #label1 {float:left;} #label2 {float:right;} | http://jsfiddle.net/nadeeth/pet4y52e/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can float each div like this.

```
.label {
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
}

.label--right {
    text-align: right;
}

<div data-role="content" class="ui-content" id="jobModuleContent">
    <div id="jmc_cJobNr">
        <div class="label">Label one</div>
        <div class="label label--right">Label two</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[You can see in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mg1spubd/1/)

Comment: And you can add `text-align: right` to the second label, otherwise it's text is almost in the middle.

Comment: thanks david, this suggestion helped me out! it works proper.

Answer (score 0):

Here a fiddle with float left and float right:
http://jsfiddle.net/rmzhyan3/

```
.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%;

}
.align--right {
    text-align: right;
}

<div data-role="content" class="ui-content" id="jobModuleContent">
    <div id="jmc_cJobNr">
        <label>Label one</label>
        <label class="align--right">Label two</label>
    </div>
</div>
```